# Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

The problem might be similar or looks duplicated but it doesn't. I Tried every possible solution on Stackoverflow and YouTube but I couldn't solve the issue with my project. I have already released the app to Google Play Store as well. but Now facing this problem.

Error:

```
Your project may be using a third-party plugin that is not compatible with the other 
plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project
```

[image: Gradle Error Explaination]

The things I have tried:

- I removed all the Gradle files and downloaded them again.
- I compare all the libs and repositories with my other projects which are working with no issue. (but have not solved this project's problem).
- I had recently added a module to add Native ads on this app and removed that too. (Not had any positive impact).
- Several times I restarted the project and rebuilt the project.  (result: nothing) I tried anything I could. the problem still exists.

Comment: hey, same issue here. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the Hilt version of the dependency was different from the Hilt plugin version.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I just changed the version of these two lines.
Replace these two lines with yours and sync the project.

Build.gradle (Project)

1. classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**7.0.4**'

Gradle.wrapper.properties

2. distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-**7.5.1**-bin.zip

I am using:

Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335, built on September 30, 2022

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing after I tried several things, the result is still the same.

It turned out that I had to update the version of the Firebase Performance library.

com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.5 to version 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I had. the same problem when I updated an old project in order to have new libraries and stuff, then started to appeared that problem.
In my case I fixed this by cheking around the project and update version libraries, for example:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin
com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin
```

And also I updated the `hilt version`

And that's it, it works again properly

Answer (score 0):

I just added below:

- Build.gradle [Project]
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
- Gradle.wrapper.properties
  distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).